# Is the medium which transmits the electrical impulse through the heart different to a nerve?

Tags: cardiology, electrophysiology

According to [Nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve)

> A nerve is an enclosed, cable-like bundle of nerve fibres called axons

Being an [Axon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axon)

> An axon (from Greek ἄξων áxōn, axis), or nerve fiber, is a long, slender projection of a nerve cell, or neuron, in vertebrates, that typically conducts electrical impulses known as action potentials

In the other hand,

[Electrical Conduction System of the heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conduction_system_of_the_heart)

> The electrical conduction system of the heart transmits signals generated usually by the sinoatrial node to cause contraction of the heart muscle.

The conduction system consists of specialised heart muscle cells

Is this conduction system consisted of cells (which I assume also transmits electrical signals through axons) different in nature to nerves?